# Cluster Configuration

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I’m looking at some of the SQL servers in a (new to me) SQL estate. The servers are configured for AOAGs; there are two nodes, both are part of the WSFC. However, if I look at the SQL Server advanced properties the 'Clustered' attribute = 'No'. Would we expect them to be in a SQL cluster sat on a WSFC? In which case I would expect the 'Clustered' attribute = 'Yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A requirement for a standard Availability Group (AG) on Windows is that you have a Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC). All nodes of the AG must be in the same WSFC.

The WSFC contains nearly all of the "smarts" necessary for the AG to determine quorum, and do health checks between nodes to ensure other nodes are online & reachable. Additionally, if your AG is configured with a Listener, your Listener and its IP are cluster resources within that WSFC.

Within your AG, you may choose to have some instances clustered into a Failover Cluster Instance (FCI), however this is not a requirement. Most AGs are created by having stand-alone instances on separate nodes within your WSFC.

AGs provide protection at the database level (or groups of databases), by maintaining separate physical copies of the database on separate compute nodes. It's possible for any/all of the separate nodes to be FCIs, but it's generally not necessary since the AG is already providing multiple compute nodes.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification AMtwo, very useful and very helpful. You have answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

This will be Yes if the server is configured as a failover cluster, this does not change based on being  a part of a WSFC or Always On AG.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> IsClustered:  Server instance is configured in a failover cluster.

1 = Clustered.

0 = Not Clustered.
"
NULL = Input is not valid, an error, or not applicable.

Query to check this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('IsClustered')
```

Comment: Hi Randi & thanks for your help, so can I assume these 2 nodes were installed as standalone instances, and that if you take the 'SQL failover cluster' option on first install the SERVERPROPERTY ('IsClustered') would = 1?

Comment: That being the case, why would you create standalone instances into a cluster and not take the 'cluster' install option, I wonder?

Comment: Yes if you run the query on a failover instance then it would return 1. And there are pro's and con's on wether to create a failover cluster or to add two instances to an always on. For example a failover cluster has shared storage, where all nodes in an always on have their own storage. Take a look here for some more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/failover-clustering-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Hi Randi, many thanks for your help again, this info along with other answers provided, has really helped clarify this area for me. I tried to mark both contributions as 'answers' but can only select 1.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped :)